# Sql Insert into with duplicate key

Tags: php, mysql, database

Ok so, im still a beginner in databases. i have this code

```
$sql="INSERT INTO complaints_members(password, complaint) VALUES ('$mypassword','$submit') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE complaint='$submit' ; ";
```

This simply updates my complaint in the existing entry. How can i insert a new entry with the same key, instead of updating the old one?

Im thinking of it like this.

1st entry is like

Password : 123

Complaint : abc

2nd would be like

Password : 123

Complaint : def

Im not very familiar with the terms of SQL, so i'm sorry in advance, and thanks for your time.

EDIT: This is how the tables are

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to do an insert or an update? Pick one.

Comment: please clearify your question, what exactly you want?

Comment: Its also not clear what your keys on this table are... can you post the table definition?

Comment: You will probably want to change password from a unique key to an index key instead so you can have duplicate password's, then you can just run the insert statement ..

Comment: If you want to insert a new entry with the same key instead of updating the old one you'd first need to remove the old one. Keys are unique on purpose

Comment: @MrPablo  I want to insert a new entry everytime a new complaint is made from the same user, not update his old one.

Comment: @prodigitalson i  posted an image of the tables.

Comment: @DominusMors, u take some srno as a primary key in complaints_memeber and password (not primary ) and complaint as a noraml fields.


** NOTE: ** It may be possible two or more user have same password too.. So avoid this and take srno as a auto incremented primary key.

Comment: As has been said before, you need unique keys for the data. The "complaints_members" table needs a unique key field added -- like an auto-increment integer field. That will solve your issue.

Comment: as i commented on rick6 , i would add an id key which i will make primary in both register and complaints_members?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have duplicate primary keys in a database. This is intentional.

Instead, consider re-designing your database so that each complaint has a unique ID (AKA a Primary Key). You should set it as something like `complaint_id` or simply `id`, and make it a PK (Primary Key) and AI (Auto-Increment). That way, when you do inserts you won't have to worry about updating the same row.

Comment: So, if i fully understand what you're saying, im gonna add in the members database an id which will be made a primary key, and im also gonna add this  id in the register database?

Comment: Every table should ideally have an ID column that is set to auto increment and be the primary key for that table. It's pretty basic stuff.

Comment: @MrPablo I dont know what's the basic stuff of databases, since im trying to learn databases for the first time, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: @DominusMors I would disagree with Mr Pablo in that EVERY table should have a PK/AI, but for most situations (yours not exempt) this is the best practice. To address your question, yes--add a field called "id" in both tables and set it to PK/AI. Then, when you add a complaint from a member--grab their ID first and save it in a new field in the "complaints" table called "linktomember", or simply "member" or "member_id". Then, when you need to retrieve all complaints by a member, look into MySQL "joins", which is how you link multiple tables together in a SELECT statement.

Comment: @rick6 Thanks a lot dude. That's exactly what i did and it worked. You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make password and complaint a [composite primary key](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/6572/composite-key)

Comment: Not the best option in this instance but would work.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference when someone asks for your table structure its better to post the text from `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` instead of an image from a visual editor.

That said the problem is that your primary key is the password field. You need to add primary keys to both tabled than can be uniquely identified and then you need to link them.

Your table structure should be more like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `register` (
   `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `number` INTEGER(255),
   `address` varchar(255),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   -- I assume that email and username should always be unique here
   UNIQUE KEY (`email`)
   UNIQUE KEY (`username`)
);

CREATE TABLE `complaints_members`
   `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `complaint` VARCHAR(255),
   `password` varchar(255),
   `member_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY (`member_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `complaints_members_register` FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `register` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

So now to create a new member complaint your SQL would look like

`INSERT INTO complaints_members(member_id, password, complaint) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`

And to get all complaints for a member:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM compalaints_members c
WHERE c.member_id = ?
```